# react lazy load external amd modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, requirejs, create-react-app

My react app has external resources outside `src/` so i have ejected `react-scripts` and disabled `ModuleScopePlugin`.
Referenced the external library in `resolve.alias` and used across the application.

```
resolve.alias: {
  'genlib': path.resolve(fs.realpathSync(process.cwd()), 'lib/genlib/js/src'),
  'config': path.resolve(fs.realpathSync(process.cwd()), 'config/dev'),
  'messages': path.resolve(fs.realpathSync(process.cwd()), 'config/messages')
}
```

`genlib` is the external library im trying to reference.

The external library is AMD using requirejs.

One of the file in the library lazy loads a class using require.

```
define('class1', ['require', ...], function(require, ...) {
  //
  require([variable], function()...)
});
```

The above require is throwing `Cannot find module 'xxx'` at runtime from `webpackEmptyContext`.

When `require` from above code is consoled then below is logged instead of require function. **Confused why `webpackEmptyContext` is consoled out instead of `webpackContext` function**

```
ƒ webpackEmptyContext(req) {
    var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'");
    e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
    throw e;
}
```

I have not changed any of the `webpack.config.js` except adding alias and disabling ModuleScopePlugin.

What else needs to be added or changed in config to lazy load amd modules.

```
webpack v4.19.1
react-dev-utils v7.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by using `ContextReplacementPlugin`.

Added below code to webpack config plugins.

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/genlib[\\/]services/, /.*$/),
```

Now a map is created with all the files in the `services` directory and `webpackContext` loads the files when required.

Comment: is that possible to use ContextReplacementPlugin along with Craco (alternative webpack override for Create React Apps)

Answer (score 0):

You will see `babel-loader` in return object of `webpack.config.js` file. `module -> rules array` First code is to run the linter

```
    {
      test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
      enforce: 'pre',
      use: [
        {
          options: {
            formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
            eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),

          },
          loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
        },
      ],
      include: [
          paths.appSrc,
          'paht/to/external-library/using/requirejs' <---- Add your external file path for loader to parse the AMD files
      ],
    }
```

Similarly include file path to test entry of JS files
 `test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,`

Can you try this and check?

Comment: I have tried this. Included path of external library for both eslint and babel-loader. But it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: can you show your resolve.alias code? 
Also, try adding libraryTarget: 'umd' in output object.

Comment: I have updated the Question with resolve.alias. Tried adding libraryTarget: 'umd'. No use :(